# Scalatestplus scalacheck for testing effectful api requires unsafeRunSync()

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalacheck, cats-effect, tagless-final

I am exploring options to implement tests for effectful api. For brevity, I have the following api.

```scala
object util {
  import cats.effect.Sync

  def stringReverser(string: String): String            = string.reverse
  def stringReverserF[F[_]: Sync](s: String): F[String] = Sync[F].delay(s.reverse)

}
```

I use `AsyncWordSpec with ScalaCheckPropertyChecks`. I had to use `unsafeRunSync`.

```scala
class SampleAsyncWordSpec extends wordspec.AnyWordSpec  
      with org.scalatestplus.scalacheck.ScalaCheckPropertyChecks {

  import util._
  import cats.effect.unsafe.implicits.global
  "String reverser[F] with property based tests" must {
    "satisfy consistency with length in original and reversed string" in {
      forAll {(s: String) => 
        val ioAssertion  = stringReverserF[IO](s).map(r => assert(s.length() == r.length() + 1))  
        ioAssertion.unsafeRunSync()
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Is there a way to avoid calling unsafeRunSync() and leave it to the framework. In `scalatestplus` with `scalacheck`, there is no mention of testing effectful api.

PS:
This is a trimmed down example of my goal. I am exploring on options to write rules for tagless final algebra.

Comment: No, **Scalatest** have no integration with effect systems like **cats-effect**. At most, you may use the `AsyncSpec` and use `unsafeRunToFuture` instead but still not ideal. - Yuu may also just consider using something like **munit** or **weaver** which have first-class support for `IO`

Comment: I have tried the same with Munit. But I got the same error that `"No implicit view available from cats.effect.IO[Unit] => org.scalacheck.Prop."`. Here is the scastie link https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DgVD45X3S5WPkOK3KaXJMw.  Looks like I am missing something consistently.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have answered, when using scalatest with scalacheck, it's not possible to avoid this.

However, there's nothing stopping you from having multiple test frameworks in your codebase if a full migration isn't possible.

I recommend using [scalacheck-effect](https://github.com/typelevel/scalacheck-effect) with the munit integration. I've successfully mixed scalacheck+munit in the same codebase before for similar reasons - `sbt test` will run them all. It's possible that you could write a scalatest integration for scalacheck-effect similar to the munit one, but I wouldn't bother honestly.

I typically also recommend using munit over scalatest for other reasons; if it's an option to migrate your tests, you should consider it. It's not as hard as you might think, depending what scalatest DSL you're using

Comment: Thanks for response. I have started evaluating munit.

Answer (score 0):

[ScalaTest](https://www.scalatest.org/) by itself, is not design for testing effects.

If you check the official docs of [cats-effects testing](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/docs/2.x/guides/testing), there is a list with the different libs that you can use. You have [cats-effect-testing](https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect-testing) which can be integrated with [ScalaTest](https://www.scalatest.org/) and [scalacheck](https://scalacheck.org/). You have [scalacheck-effect](https://github.com/typelevel/scalacheck-effect) too that adds support for writing effectful properties with the shape `A => F[Assertion]`.

Also if you check [cats-effect - testing # best practices](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/docs/2.x/guides/testing#best-practices) it says

> Avoid using `unsafe*` methods in tests, the same as you'd avoid them in
> "main" code. Writing tests to be structured the same way as "normal"
> code results in tests that are less likely to be flaky, act as
> executable documentation, and remain easy to read.
>
> Use a compatible framework's support for writing `IO[Assertion]` style
> tests.

So, what you are doing in the test you wrote as an example, it's not exactly good

Comment: Yes. I know that calling `unsafeRunSync` is not good which is why I am here. Recommendation to cats-effect-testng is fine. But my question is about how to use `AnyWordSpec with ScalaCheckPropertyChecks` to use test Effects ? It looks like there is still a need to write an implicit to convert IO[Assertion] => Prop by using cats-effect-testing. Will evaluate the complexity. I would prefer to keep dependency of libraries as simple as possible for my own understanding.